# Laptop web cam not recognised by Linux Mint

Tags: linux, laptop

I have a 64-bit Linux Mint 10 but it does not recognise my Lenovo Y650 camera.

When I try to open the Video4Linux Control Panel, I get the following error:

> Unable to open file /dev/video0 
>   Permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently don't have permission to access the video device as your user.

The best way to fix this is to put yourself into whatever group owns that devices. A quick and dirty way to do this is with this command: `groupadd -A $(whoami) $(stat -c %G /dev/video0)` (adds your user to whatever group owns that devices node). On my system that would be video, but **beware** that if that devices is owned by root, you end up with your user in the root group (not advised!).

The not so good way to do this but that would work if your distro doesn't have a sensible group ownership of that device node is to open up the device to be read and written by all users with something like `sudo chmod 777 /dev/video0`.

Comment: This is what I get as an error message: "cannot access `/dev/video0': No such file or directory"

Comment: Wait now, "Permission denied" from your initial question is different than "no such file". Which is it? As root if you look in /dev is there a video0 node? Some other video node? Maybe you're just trying to use the wrong one?

Comment: My apologies. It's the latter now "No such file or directory." Btw, I think copied the error message directly the first time. Seems really odd to me as well.

Comment: What do you see here: `sudo ls -al /dev | grep video`

Comment: crw-rw----   1 root video    10, 175 2011-04-26 14:43 agpgart
crw-rw----   1 root video    29,   0 2011-04-26 14:43 fb0

Comment: Ya you don't have a video device with the name Video4Linux was expecting :( Check out `dmesg` when you plug/unplug the camera for clues as to what else it might be called. Maybe you need to load a module for it?

Comment: Hmm.. it is a built-in laptop camera. What should I be looking for when checking out `dmesg`?

Comment: In that case I doubt you have the right module installed. Try `modprove uvc` or figure out what kernel module matches your camera/laptop model. When you load the module you should get some clues in `dmesg` and a device node for it.

Comment: I followed the instructions on this [site](http://kylewilliams.co.za/2009/03/05/getting-the-lenovo-sl300-camera-to-work-on-linux) and got `[ 3456.159058] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[ 3456.162709] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 3456.162713] USB Video Class driver (v0.1.0)` in `dmesg`. Unfortunately, I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: That sounds good. Now check to see if you have any video devices under /dev again using `find /dev -iname 'video*'`

Comment: No, unfortunately there are no matches for items named 'video*'. Here are the contents of the `/dev` folder: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/yMJbSnKt).